# Movie about a team of people drilling to the center of the Earth to save humanity

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching a movie that the whole premise of it was that the Earth was dying, so the U.S. government assigned a team to drill down to the Earth's core with a huge drill vehicle and explode a bomb in it. I remember one scene in which the drill goes into a huge cave full of crystals, and I think that lava starts to come out of the walls.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you watch this?

Comment: I can't recall, but I remember the movie seeming old

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is probably [*The Core*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298814/) (2003); quoting the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Core#Plot):

> Several small, disparate incidents involving the Earth's magnetic field cause scientists led by geophysicist Dr. Josh Keyes and scientists Dr. Serge Leveque and Dr. Conrad Zimsky to conclude that the Earth's molten core has stopped rotating. Unless restarted, the field is set to collapse within months, exposing the surface to devastating solar radiation.
>
> The U.S. government backs a secret project to build a vessel **to drill to the core and release nuclear weapons to restart the rotation**. They utilize the work of Dr. Ed "Braz" Brazzelton who has developed "Unobtainium", a material that can convert extreme heat into electricity, as well as a laser-based high-speed drilling array.

Comment: Yes! This is the movie, thank you so much. This has been bothering me for so long lol

Comment: This film is the perfect sweet spot between awful and awesome.

Comment: That they literally called the material unobtanium shows they knew exactly how ridiculous they were being.

Comment: There was also the scanning device that can see through a hundred feet of lead which they casually stand in front of as well.   I kind of have a soft spot for the film _because_ it's so terrible, and Aaron Eckhart is great.

Comment: @DanielRoseman When they explained about the material that kept on getting stronger as it got hotter, I thought "This is ridiculous." Then when they said it was called unobtanium, I was like..."Okay, I'll give them a pass...this time."

Comment: This is one of the dumbest movies ever made and a highlight of its dumbness is the shuttle landing, where we learn that the shuttle used a magnetic compass for navigation.

Comment: @DKNguyen it was not heat it was pressure "More pressure makes it stronger". I was like 10 years old when I saw this movie and I was like that's not possible :P.

Comment: For a fun read about how had the physics are: http://www.intuitor.com/moviephysics/core.html

Comment: @DanielRoseman Unobtanium was also the mineral on Pandora in the Avatar movies. Does that make them part of the same cinematic universe?

Comment: @Barmar Nope. The reason it's so unobtainable is because they need to import it from a different setting.

Comment: I'm sure Worf was in that. (Michael Dorn)

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Does that show they *knew* how ridiculous it was?  The other explanation is that a screenwriter came across the word "unobtainium" and didn't realize it was a tongue-in-cheek placeholder, and thought it was a real name for a hypothesized wonder-material, or something like that.  I haven't seen this or Avatar, but I thought Avatar was supposed to be a serious movie.  If this movie generally knows it's being silly, maybe the creators of this one did realize they were being ridiculous?

Comment: @PeterCordes When the mission to drill to the Earth's core is first brought to him, Aaron Eckhart's character lays out all the things (heat, pressure, etc) that would make it physically impossible to do. Braz then simply replies, "But what if you *could*?", and proceeds to bring up unobtanium, this magic metal with exactly the right properties to make it possible. It's unironically one of my favourite movie scenes, because it's so clearly just the writers going "we *know* this is bullshit, we don't care, and neither should you".

Comment: @Barmar For the Core and Avatar, if you mean the same cinematic universe of bad writing, then yes!!!!

Comment: There's a molecule called "Arsole", apparently xD. BTW, I'm sure pressure *can* make things stronger (think custard), and pressure is similar to heat. Soo yeah, makes [more sense than it first seems](https://www.techtarget.com/whatis/definition/unobtainium) ;)

Comment: @PeterCordes The quote from the movie: "It's actual name has 37 syllables... I... I call it Unobtainium" - after which character (Braz) laughs sheepishly. He "binds crystals within Tungsten-Titanium matrix at soopercool temperatures", which makes it expensive to make. I guess screenwriter at least did basic due dilligence and "Unobtanium" is, actually, a joke among the crew in the movie.

Comment: @AcePL: Thanks, that sounds a lot less dumb than if Unobtainium was its "official" name,.  A nickname used by some people involved with its creation sound like something that could happen.

Comment: (*reads the answer...*) Tugg Speedman's entire career in *Tropic Thunder* was a parody of an actual film!?!

Comment: Unobtainium is a real name they give to stuff that can't be easily accessed.